# Capitalizing 1st character of each word in <apex:pageblockTable

Tags: apex, visualforce, pageblocktable

How to convert 1st letter of each word to `uppercase`. Is there a way to achieve this?

Here is my visualforce page:

```
<apex:pageblockTable value="{!myWrapperList}" var="mw">
  <apex:column value="{!mw.name}"/>
  <apex:column value="{!mw.status}"/>
</apex:pageBlockTable>
```

Output is something like this:

```
eric     active
john     inactive
joe      active
```

Desired output should be first character upper case:

```
Eric     Active
John     Inactive
Joe      Active
```

Comment: Any luck on this one?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It should be possible to manipulate a single value using just merge syntax:

```
<apex:column value="{!UPPER(LEFT(mw.name, 1)) & MID(mw.name, 2, LEN(mw.name))}" />
```

---

Here is a more elegant approach if you wish to use `Apex`:

```
static String capitalizeWords(String input)
{
    String output = '';
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile('(\\w+|\\W+)').matcher(input);
    while (m.find()) output += m.group().capitalize();
    return output;
}
```

The above can handle whitespace characters outside of just a single space, and doesn't need to do nearly as much string manipulation.

While it is slightly slower, this approach also works for edge cases like having a line break character right before a word. Consider:

```
String input = 'alice and bob\ncarrie and denise\nelbert and frank';
```

**This Approach**

> Alice And Bob
>   Carrie And Denise
>   Elbert And Frank

**Prior Approach**

> Alice And Bob
>   carrie And Denise
>   elbert And Frank

Comment: why can't be access this method from vfp i have tried doing something like this `<apex:column value="{!capitalizeWords(mw.status)}"/>` then getting this error `Unknown function capitalizeWords. Check spelling` i have this method as static in the controller class

Comment: You can't call `Apex` methods in merge fields, other than `get`/`set` property methods. See my top section on how to use a merge field...

Comment: For title casing, you can use @AdrianLarson solution above, but first convert the input to lowercase via `input.toLowerCase()` in order to handle input with all caps.

Answer (score 0):

As salesforce does not provide method for this, you can try below option.

Referring to below link solution given by @brovasi,

[capitalizing 1st character of each word in a string](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/28130/capitalizing-1st-character-of-each-word-in-a-string)

```
String rep_name = 'david john mitch doe';
List<String> elems = rep_name.split(' ');
rep_name = '';
for (String x : elems)
{
    rep_name += x.substring(0,1).toUpperCase()+x.substring(1,x.length()) + ' ';
}
System.debug('>>>'+rep_name);
```

Hope this helps :)