# Find all non-alpha characters in string (excluding special alpha chars) and capitalise each word before/after the character

Tags: apex, regular-expressions, pattern, matcher

I'm looking to capitalise each part of a string that precedes/follows a special character and found this [post](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/127935/capitalizing-1st-character-of-each-word-in-apexpageblocktable) which does the trick nicely. Only problem is it also sees characters which are special **alpha** characters (eg ô, ê, ë...) as part of the check. How do I get this to ignore those, or rather see them as acceptable alpha characters?

```
public static String capitaliseString(String word) {
   String name = '';
   Matcher m = Pattern.compile('(\\w+|\\W+)').matcher(word);
   while (m.find())
     name += m.group().toLowerCase().capitalize();
   system.debug('####util_helper capitaliseString: ' + word + ' ## ' + name);
   return name;
}
```

For example, if I pass it a string like *o'hägen-daß* I need it to return *O'Hägen-Daß*, but instead it returns *O'HÄGen-Daß* as it sees the ä as a special character.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`\w` is the shortcut character class for ascii word characters; a-z, A-Z, _, 0-9

You'll need a more extensive character class.

From [this question on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16980870/regex-matching-letter-characters), it appears that Java allows positive and negative matching on larger unicode categories and blocks using `\p{<identifier>}` (positive match) and `\P{<identifier>}` (negative match).

The difference being what you might expect. Lower case 'p' = do a positive match, upper case 'P' = do a negative match.

Since Apex compiles to Java bytecode, figured it was worth a shot. Turns out that we do have the ability to use these (we just need to change the one backslash to two, as usual).

Simply replacing your regex `'(\\w+|\\W+)'` with one that does the same, but for *all* unicode (not just Latin++) characters `(\\p{L}+|\\P{L}+)` seems to return the result you want.

That could likely be narrowed down a bit.

Answer (score 0):

I think this will be helpful.

```
public static String toProperCase(String request){
    List<String> responseList = new List<String>();
    request = request.toLowerCase().normalizeSpace(); // To convert to lower case and remove unwanted spaces within string
    List<String> requestList = request.splitByCharacterType(); // Split the string at different character type
    for(String word : requestList){
        responseList.add(word.capitalize()); // Capitalize first character of each split word
    }
    return String.join(responseList, '');
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Salesforce Stack Exchange (SFSE)! Your contribution is welcome, but your answer is essentially a "code dump" which is frowned upon. Here on SFSE the *why* (explanation) is often as or more important than the *how* (code) in an answer. Please [edit](https://salesforce.stackexchange.com/posts/375307/edit) your answer to explain - even briefly (but enough to understand) - what in your code is different from the code posted in the question & why that solves the problem. *(In other words, how exactly `splitByCharacterType()` helps?)* Maybe include actual output using the OPs example.